# Android Studio and java compiler does not an SDK constant

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm using Android-Studio Beta 0.8.1.4 configured tu use Lillipop SDK

When inserting following code:

```
String action = ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION;
String iaction = ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION_IMMEDIATE;
```

The first line is ok but the second line cause problem both for IDE and for the compiler:

```
ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION_IMMEDIATE
```

is undefined identifier

Extremely strange because the offending constant IS declared in the android.net.ConnectivityManager.java

Comment: Not according to the docs I'm looking at; please include what API level you're targeting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That definition is not part of the public API.  From the AOSP sources:

```
/**
 * Identical to {@link #CONNECTIVITY_ACTION} broadcast, but sent without any
 * applicable {@link Settings.Secure#CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE_DELAY}.
 *
 * @hide
 */
@SdkConstant(SdkConstantType.BROADCAST_INTENT_ACTION)
public static final String CONNECTIVITY_ACTION_IMMEDIATE =
        "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE_IMMEDIATE";
```

Note the `@hide` annotation.  That removes it from the public API so it is not part of the SDK.